Process tab-separated (tsv) file with xargs while preserving quotes
I have a tab-separated-file myfile.tsv of form:
"a"      "b"
"c"      "d"

How can I process it with xargs (i.e. what args I need to pass) to pass these fields as two arguments to an external program while preserving all characters, including double-quotes (as I don't want to mess-up escaping and this is crucial if values in the tsv are actually JSON-formatted) and splitting by tab into external command's arguments?
E.g. I'd like to have cat myfile.tsv | xargs ... python -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv[1:])' to print
['"a"', '"b"']
['"c"', '"d"']

Thanks!

Why not just read the tsv file in python?

I can of course do that, but in this question I wonder of whether it's possible to achieve the same with raw xargs. Basically I'm trying to process some jq-produced @tsv-output. Of course, workarounds are plenty, and I am not blocked.

Can the quoted fields contain blanks, tabs, newlines or [escaped] double quotes, any of which are possible in general in a TSV file? Can some fields NOT be double quoted in the input and, if so, does it matter if they are double quoted or not in the output?

You should use NULL chars as delimiters for xargs:
tr '\t\n' '\0' < myfile.tsv | xargs -0 -L2 python -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv[1:])' 
['"a"', '"b"']
['"c"', '"d"']



This assumes there are no literal newlines or tabs between quotes anywhere.

OP states it comes from json: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

JSON can very well accommodate any ASCII string; encoding newline and tab as \n and \t respectively is recommended but strictly optional.

Correct, and this is not touching escaped chars

printf '\\n\\t\n\t' | tr '\t\n' '\0' | xxd

not sure why you want/need xargs , a trivial example to process
cat parseMe.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for row in sys.stdin:
    lst=list(row.strip().split('\t'))
    print(f'{lst}')

cat myfile.tsv | ./parseMe.py 
['"a"', '"b"']
['"c"', '"d"']
['"e"', '"f"']

feel free to ignore if not suitable / I've missed the essence of why you need xargs.

That breaks if there's a tab in the quoted values. Python has a csv module; use that with tab instead of comma as the field separator.

that'd break all of the submissions afaics. if the user has embedded tabs within each field then there's other issues.

Yeah, but yours is the simplest one to make really robust.

Bit hacky but this works:
$ cat myfile.tsv | xargs -n2 -I{} bash -c 'sed -e s/^/\"/ -e s/$/\"/ -e s/\ /\"\ \"/ <<<"{}"' | python -c 'import fileinput 
for line in fileinput.input():
  print(line.split())
'
['"a"', '"b"']
['"c"', '"d"']


If you're not sure that there are exactly 2 fields per line, you have to read the file line by line and then split each line individually.
To demonstrate it I added a line to the tsv file, including a backslash, as these may get treated as an escape character by some tools like read:
$ cat myfile.tsv
"a"     "b"
"c"     "d"
"e"     "f"     "g\t"

To split on tab, you have to set the delimiter to tab. We can do this with $(printf \\t).
$ cat myfile.tsv | while read -r line ; do echo -n "$line" | xargs -d "$(printf \\t)" python -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv[1:])' ; done
['"a"', '"b"']
['"c"', '"d"']
['"e"', '"f"', '"g\\t"']

However we can also do the line splitting at once by read by setting the IFS variable (input field separator), reading into an array variable and passing it to the next command (python):
$ cat myfile.tsv | while IFS="$(printf \\t)" read -ra line ; do python -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv[1:])' "${line[@]}" ; done
['"a"', '"b"']
['"c"', '"d"']
['"e"', '"f"', '"g\\t"']

